# How do I hold and compare values in a Boolean Satisfiability Expression?

Tags: c, algorithm, boolean

In problems like this, [image]

If I were solving a problem in C using recursion where I'd have to find all TRUE or FALSE values for X1, X2 AND X3 satisfying the expression, how would I compare the alignment (whether or not a variable is NOT like X2 in the first clause)against actual true and false values? I could use 0 and 1 and recursively try all permutations, but I'm unsure how to actually go about computing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about your question, but you have 4 boolean values which can be represented by 4 bits. By exploiting the internal respresentation for integrals, you can make that in a `for` loop to check for all possible combinations:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 16; ++i ) // That's 2^4
{
    int x1 = i & 1;
    int x2 = i & 2;
    int x3 = i & 4;
    int x4 = i & 8;

    if( ( x1 || !x2 || !x3 ) && ( x1 || x2 || x4 ) )
        ... the expression holds for this combination, store it somewhere ...
}
```

Comment: Could you try explaining the bit about how you are exploiting the internal representation for "integrals" and what your reasoning was?

Answer (score 1):

`bool x1[2]={false,true};

    bool x2[2]={false,true};

    bool x3[2]={false,true};

    bool x4[2]={false,true};

    for(int i1=0;i1！=2;i1++)

    {

     for(int i2=0;i2!=2;i2++)

     {

      for(int i3=0;i3!=2;i3++)

      {

       for(int i4=0;i4!=2;i4++)

       {
         if((x1[i1]||!x2[i2]||!x3[i3])&&(x1[i1]||x2[i2]||x4[i4]))

         .......the expression holds, do something you need

       }

      }

     }

   }`

The thought of this answer is the same with K-ballo, but obviously, he had smarter codes.